# let foot stay in place and body move forward trhough animation - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a walking animation and i have colliders on the feet with a max friction physics material so that the foot stays in place. I want that, when one foot is on the ground and the ohter foot in the air, the upper body gets moved forward by the animation.
Is this possible?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface

Comment: Could you explain how this could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for procedural animation. Using friction is not the way to go about it.

Unity's animator has some built in functions for humanoid characters. You first need to create a [Rig](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/intro-to-unity-rigs#), apply an [IK pass](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) to the animation layer and then you'll be able to use functions like [Animator.SetIKPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetIKPosition.html) to position your legs in the right spot.

Comment: Will the whole then automatically move with the legs? If yes then i will try it. And mark as solved.

Comment: @ChickenMeister no you would still need to write a piece of code that places the foot in the right spot, lifts it in an arc when stepping and synchronizes with the other foot. Sadly I don't have the right code on hand, so you will have take some inspiration for that from this [official Unity Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acMK93A-FSY) instead. They're using a bit of a different method, you can either copy that or adapt my previous suggestion.